# Specify Cython output file

Tags: python, c++, cython

It seems that by default setup from distutils.core with cmdclass set to build_ext, compiles a *.cpp* or *.c* file in the current working directory.  Is there a way to determine where the generated C code is written to?  Otherwise, a repository will be littered with generated code.

For example, this file, *setup.py*, will write a file, *example.c*, to the current working directory:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
      ext_modules = cythonize("example.pyx"))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass the option `build_dir="directory name"` to `Cythonize`

```
# rest of file as before
setup(
      ext_modules = cythonize("example.pyx",
                              build_dir="build"))
```

The above code will put the generated c files in the directory "build" (which makes sense, since by default it's where distutils puts temporary object files and so forth when it's building).

---

My original answer had `working`, not `build_dir`. Thanks to @ArthurTacca for pointing out that that no longer seems to be right.

Comment: The correct option seems to be "build_dir" not "working". Perhaps it changed in a recent version of Cython. To avoid clashing with other build files, it's probably best not to just use "build". A subdirectory like "build/cython" would be better.

Comment: At a quick glance you look to be right - thanks. Looking at the code on github I can't see where it's changed since 2015 so who knows where I got it from (but I imagine it must have worked at the time...). I'll update it once I've confirmed that it does work.

Comment: But how to specify a path to build the .so files?

Comment: Doesn't work on .so files

Comment: @TomSawyer The question wasn't about .so files

Answer (score 14):

After initializing an Extension, the parameters can be set to create c in temp directory.

```
module  = Extension("temp", "temp.pyx")
module.cython_c_in_temp = True
```

Comment: I think this is a slightly better solution than my answer.

Comment: This solution solved my problem as well but is adding attributes to an `Extension` documented anywhere?

Comment: No, but we do stuff like that all the time in cython.  When I get a chance, we should document all the options

Answer (score 8):

Your setup.py is fine.

To get it to build to a different location, invoke python in the following way:

```
python setup.py build_ext --build-lib <build directory>
```

I use the following make rules to automate this:

```
python_lib_dir=src/lib

cython_output = $(patsubst $(python_lib_dir)/%.pyx,$(python_lib_dir)/%.so, $(shell find $(python_lib_dir) -name '*.pyx'))

$(cython_output):%.so:%.pyx      
    python setup.py build_ext --build-lib $(python_lib_dir)
```